# How to get the list of all tag names of json arrays within a json object in android/java

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have a small problem parsing json response because it constantly keeps on getting updated whenever i send a request.All the examples I have seen makes us provide the tag name. My question is that I am trying to parse data from a request sent through an API and I want to list out all the tags of all JSON Arrays existing within a JSON Object before I start parsing. Is it possible in android. http://api.yamgo.tv/channel?apiKey=187abeefc53f900600dc0fc5b8f913a0&token=892e069fa48eead5e7f84cddafe7f0ba
This is the request I am sending and it gives me a json response. which has channels as a json object and within it many json arrays with tags like bollywood, entertainment, music,etc. Use an online parser for the response to check it out. I want this list of array names. How can I do it. Could anyone please help. Thanks.

Comment: There is some mistake in above link because this is giving me null pointer exception.

Comment: In Dom Parsing this is giving me error of null pointer exception before parse any tag.

Comment: ok i guess there may be a need to change the apikey and token so thats why u are getting the error and I figured to get it done using Iterator. posting the solution shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually figured it out with a small help from one of my friend. Needed the use of Iterator object.
Here is the snippet of code

```
JSONObject channels = jobj.getJSONObject(TAG_CHANNELS);
    Iterator<?> keys=channels.keys();
    while( keys.hasNext() )
    {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        Log.e("Key", key);
        if( channels.get(key) instanceof JSONArray ){
            jsontags.add(key);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where jsonObj is the JSONObject which contains some data,
By these following code you can get only field names, if u want for column values then you can add further for value for keys.

```
List<String> listArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator iter = jsonObj.keys();
    int count=0;
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        listArray.add((String)iter.next());
        count +=1;
    }
    System.out.println(listArray);

output: [projector, video_conference, polycom, lcd, digital_phone, speaker_phone]
```