# How to check if the JSON has keys from the list of strings

Tags: java, json

Am in a situation where, I have a list of strings and a JSON. I want to check if the JSON contains all the keys which exists in the list. If any of the key doesn't exist in the list then I want to remove that particular key:value pair from JSON itself. How can I achieve this?

lets say I have a list `['name','password']`, and 
JSON as `{"name":"veeru","pass":"123","age":"23"}` , 
now since age doesn't exists in list i want to remove that entry from my JSON itself. How can I achieve this?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12510289/1283215)

Comment: Parser the json using some JSON parser, get the key value compare it with the list, and construct a new json with the values found in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just make a new object.

```
var obj = {"name":"veeru","pass":"123","age":"23"};

var strippedObj = {};
['name', 'password'].forEach(function(key) {
    if(key in obj) {
         strippedObj[key] = obj[key];
    } else {
         throw 'key ' + key + ' not found';
    }
});

console.log(strippedObject); //{name:'verru', pass:'123'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged java, you probably want to convert the json data to a java domain object.

This could be done using [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and the below code:

```
public class JsonSample
{
    static class User
    {
        String name;
        char[] pass;

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName( String name )
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public char[] getPass()
        {
            return pass;
        }

        public void setPass( char[] pass )
        {
            this.pass = pass;
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        String json = "{\"name\":\"veeru\",\"pass\":\"123\",\"age\":\"23\"}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false );

        User user = mapper.readValue( json, User.class );

        System.out.println( user.name );
        System.out.println( new String( user.pass ) );

        mapper.writeValue( System.out, user );
    }
}
```