# Check And Read inner json array which is in main json array in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to check and read a JSON array which is in main JSON array.

How can I check if main jsonarray has a "submenu" array that I want to read?

I implemented my code here but it gives me no value in submenu array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
  listDataHeader.add(jarray.getJSONObject(i).get(ClassVariable.MENU.TITLE).toString());

  // For Getting Main Menu in ArrayList
  String title = jarray.getJSONObject(i).get(ClassVariable.MENU.TITLE).toString();
  String uid = jarray.getJSONObject(i).get(ClassVariable.MENU.UID).toString();
  String pid = jarray.getJSONObject(i).get(ClassVariable.MENU.PID).toString();

  HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put(ClassVariable.MENU.TITLE, title);
  map.put(ClassVariable.MENU.UID, uid);
  map.put(ClassVariable.MENU.PID, pid);
  headerarraylist.add(map);

  if (jarray.getJSONObject(i).has(ClassVariable.SUBMENU.SUBMENU)) {
    JSONArray jarraysubmenu  = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(ClassVariable.SUBMENU.SUBMENU);
    Log.e("JarraySubmenu","----->" + jarraysubmenu);
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot of sample JSON]

Comment: if(jarray.getJSONObject(i).has(ClassVariable.SUBMENU.SUBMENU))
                {   
                    JSONArray jarraysubmenu =jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(ClassVariable.SUBMENU.SUBMENU);

                    Log.e("JarraySubmenu","----->"+jarraysubmenu);

                } why this is not work for check jsonarray (SUB_MENU) condition

Comment: check length of jsonArray, if > 0 then get subMeny

Comment: but submenu array is not for all position you can see in my image on 0 position have no tag submenu but in 1 position of menu have tag sub_menu so first i want to check if SUB_MENU ARRAY is there if yes than i can read

Comment: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=713e02c

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508823/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-tag-names-of-json-arrays-within-a-json-object-in-andr, you can get all tag and check if have that do your job

Comment: @AndroidPower : try to check as if SUBMENU JSONArray present or not : `if(!jarray.getJSONObject(i).isNull(ClassVariable.SUBMENU.SUBMENU) && jarray.getJSONObject(i).has(ClassVariable.SUBMENU.SUBMENU) && ){....your code}`

Comment: http://www.bridge.co.at/webservices/services.php?method=menu  this is the link for webservice implement your code but now is give me error

Comment: 02-03 17:06:00.641: W/System.err(2311): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 12, size is 12
02-03 17:06:00.656: W/System.err(2311):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
02-03 17:06:00.656: W/System.err(2311):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
02-03 17:06:00.668: W/System.err(2311):  at com.bridge.app.HomeListActivity$HomeListAsynctask.doInBackground(HomeListActivity.java:384)
02-03 17:06:00.668: W/System.err(2311):  at com.bridge.app.HomeListActivity$HomeListAsynctask.doInBackground(HomeListActivity.java:1)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check if main jsonarray has a "submenu" array that I want to
>   read?

***Here you go:***

```
JsonArray jarr = jarray.getJSONObject(i).optJSONArray(ClassVariable.SUBMENU.SUBMENU);

if(jarr.length()>0 && jarr!=null)
{
    SUBMENU Jarray is present
}
else
{
    SUBMENU Jarray is Not present
}
```